# How to fit text block into div?

Tags: php, html, css, string

I have a PHP script that echo's a string into an html `div`.

The div has room for only 50 chars in width, so if the string is longer, I have to cut it in to how ever many lines it takes.

So I can use `strlen` to see where I should be cutting the string and echo a `<br>`. Problem is, I don't want to cut it in the middle of a word.

I had a solution in mind, but it seems that i'm over complicating this.

Thanks,

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/717328/how-to-explode-string-right-to-left First you cut it, then you explode it by spaces and pop the last word off.

Comment: You can use `textarea` as well and using CSS make it look like ordinary text: http://jsfiddle.net/dPnDp/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just add an attribute `class="wrapping"` to the div you want to have this behaviour, and add this css to your HTML page:

```
div.wrapping {
    word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.totallyphp.co.uk/code/shorten_a_text_string.htm

You can use this simple function to shorten your text

Answer (score 0):

There are some examples in the PHP doc page for `substr`. Copy/pasting a couple:

```
$str = "aa bb ccc ddd ee fff gg hhh iii";
echo substr(($str=wordwrap($str,$len,'$$')),0,strpos($str,'$$'));
```

and

```
function _substr($str, $length, $minword = 3)
{
    $sub = '';
    $len = 0;

    foreach (explode(' ', $str) as $word)
    {
        $part = (($sub != '') ? ' ' : '') . $word;
        $sub .= $part;
        $len += strlen($part);

        if (strlen($word) > $minword && strlen($sub) >= $length)
        {
            break;
        }
    }

    return $sub . (($len < strlen($str)) ? '...' : '');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[`wordwrap`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php)`($string, 50, "<br>\n")`

Answer (score 0):

write function

```
// Original PHP code by Chirp Internet: www.chirp.com.au 
// Please acknowledge use of this code by including this header. 
function myTruncate($string, $limit, $break=".", $pad="...") { 
    // return with no change if string is shorter than $limit 
    if(strlen($string) <= $limit) return $string; 
       // is $break present between $limit and the end of the string? 
       if(false !== ($breakpoint = strpos($string, $break, $limit))) { 
           if($breakpoint < strlen($string) - 1) { 
                $string = substr($string, 0, $breakpoint) . $pad; 
           } 
       }
 return $string;
 }
```