# Regex to split string with the last occurrence of a dot, colon or underscore

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

we have thousands of rows of data containing articlenumers in all sort of formats and I need to split off main article number from a size indicator. There is (almost) always a dot, dash or underscore between some last characters (not always 2).

In short: Data is main article number + size indicator, the separator is differs but 1 of 3 .-_

**Question**: how do I split main article number + size indicator? My regex below isn't working that I built based on some Google-ing.

`preg_match('/^(.*)[\.-_]([^\.-_]+)$/', $sku, $matches);`

Sample data + expected result

```
AR.110052.15-40 [AR.110052.15 & 40]
BI.533.41-41 [BI.533.41 & 41]
CG.00554.000-39 [CG.00554.000 & 39]
LL.PX00.SC004-40 [LL.PX00.SC004 & 40]
LOS.HAPPYSOCKS.1X [LOS.HAPPYSOCKS & 1X]
MI.PMNH300043-XXXXL [MI.PMNH300043 & XXXXL]
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11134004/regex-that-will-match-the-last-occurrence-of-dot-in-a-string has a nice regex with a lookahead which looks nice and simple. Personally I'd do an `strrpos` and split on the max of the indices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to move the `-` to the end of character class to make the regex engine parse it as a literal hyphen:

```
^(.*)[._-]([^._-]+)$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tQQufi/1). Actually, even [`^(.+)[._-](.+)$`](https://regex101.com/r/tQQufi/2) will work.

- `^` - matches the start of string
- `(.*)` - Group 1 capturing any 0+ chars as many as possible up to the last...
- `[._-]` - either `.` or `_` or `-`
- `([^._-]+)` - Group 2: one or more chars other than `.`, `_` and `-`
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: Great answer. Alternatively, the hyphen can be escaped: `\-`

Comment: Yes, it can, but the best practice is to keep the pattern tidy with as little escaping as possible. Also, a best practice is to always keep the hyphen at the end/start of the character class to avoid issues like here, when OP forgot to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `preg_split()` instead of `preg_match()` because:

1. this isn't a validation task, it is an extraction task and
2. `preg_split()` returns the exact desired array compared to `preg_match()` which carries the unnecessary fullstring match in its returned array.

Limit the number of elements produced (like you would with `explode()`'s limit parameter.

No capture groups are needed at all.

Greedily match zero or more characters, then just before matching the latest occurring delimiter, restart the fullstring match with `\K`.  This will effectively use the matched delimiter as the character to explode on and it will be "lost" in the explosion.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/qIAbK))

```
$strings = [
    'AR.110052.15-40',
    'BI.533.41-41',
    'CG.00554.000-39',
    'LL.PX00.SC004-40',
    'LOS.HAPPYSOCKS.1X',
    'MI.PMNH300043-XXXXL',
];

foreach ($strings as $string) {
    var_export(preg_split('~.*\K[._-]~', $string, 2));
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => 'AR.110052.15',
  1 => '40',
)
array (
  0 => 'BI.533.41',
  1 => '41',
)
array (
  0 => 'CG.00554.000',
  1 => '39',
)
array (
  0 => 'LL.PX00.SC004',
  1 => '40',
)
array (
  0 => 'LOS.HAPPYSOCKS',
  1 => '1X',
)
array (
  0 => 'MI.PMNH300043',
  1 => 'XXXXL',
)
```

Comment: [Effectively the same as How to explode only on the last occurring delimiter?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/717328/2943403)